# How to do a data overlap independently column in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to have something similar to the image below, but the columns representing the classes all stack together now. How do I separate them and allow them to load dynamically as well?

Also I need a legend that says green is band 1, yellow is band 2, orange is band 3 and red is band 4, how do i do that as well? My code is in the JS Fiddle page. I am not allowed to use jQuery, need to use pure JavaScript.

```
var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo : 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Topic & Subtopic Mastery'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Average Level-Stream Mastery vs Average Class Mastery'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: topics
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'Mastery'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' %'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false
            }
        },
        series: resultsData
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kscwx139/2/

[image]

Comment: Apart of answer below, you can use pointPlacement: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement with number value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution you are looking for with specifying x and y axis data for level and giving appropriate width to the point.

```
$(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            if (i == 0) {
                i++;
                return Highcharts.Color(color)
                    .setOpacity(1)
                    .get('rgba');
            } else {
                i++;
                return Highcharts.Color(color)
                    .setOpacity(0.5)
                    .get('rgba');
            }
        });
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                borderColor: null
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Mailboxes over Quota'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Mailbox Size in MB'
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ["Overall Topic", "Topic 1", "Topic 2"],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                allowDecimals: false,

            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, '.', ',');
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Level',
                color: colors[0],
                data: [{
                    y: 86,
                    x: 0.25
                }, {
                    y: 80,
                    x: 1.25
                }, {
                    y: 95,
                    x: 2.25
                }],
                pointWidth: 80
            }, {
                name: '4A',
                data: [90, 88, 97]
            }, {
                name: '4B',
                data: [95, 78, 92]
            }, {
                name: '4C',
                data: [80, 69, 84]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

To show in label inside your column you can use below code.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.series.name;
            },
            y: 25,
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it in action at this [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6asgyc6/)

Comment: Thanks. But there is one issue, how do u resize the width responsively for that columns behind? The columns infront do get resized responsively by default.

Comment: You need to take care of pointWidth: 80 in level series for that purpose.

Comment: Ya i was wondering how too. But i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670977/highcharts-set-column-width-dynamically. For the colors of the legend i am using create empty series for the mastery levels...